# Reference for timeline Krishna and Barbarika dialogue

Tags: krishna, vyasa, mahabharata

In [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarika) article about Barbarika, Wikipedia says

> Barbarika gave his head to him in charity. This happened on the 12th
> day of the Shukla Paksha (bright half) of the month of Phalgun on
> Tuesday

But I couldn't find any source or citation listed. Does Mahabharata mention this date anywhere. Or is it mentioned any other scripture?

What's the source of this claim?

Comment: I heard Barbarika is not in the Vyasa Mahabharata. He is in regional, folktale versions.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa Oh is it so??? Great into Biit where does this claim come from?